# Error in JavaScript Elliptic curve cryptography to import the private key: Bad private key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, private-key, elliptic-curve

I want to encrypt and decrypt the message based on ECIES using this library [JavaScript Elliptic curve cryptography library](https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto).
I want to import my private key and get the public key from it because I do not have a new private key generated each time I run the code.

The code:

```
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

var privateKeyB = 'efae5b8156d785913e244c39ca5b9bee1a46875d123d2f49bbeb0a91474118cf';
var publicKeyB = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKeyB);
console.log(publicKeyB.toString('hex'))

// Encrypting the message for B.
eccrypto.encrypt(publicKeyB, Buffer.from("msg to b")).then(function(encrypted) {
  // B decrypting the message.
  eccrypto.decrypt(privateKeyB, encrypted).then(function(plaintext) {
    console.log("Message to part B:", plaintext.toString());
  });
});
```

However, the code is not working and shows this error:

```
    throw new Error(message || "Assertion failed");
    ^
    Error: Bad private key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eccrypto.getPublic()` expects a `Buffer` as argument, not a `string`. Try this instead:

```js
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

var privateKeyB = Buffer.from('efae5b8156d785913e244c39ca5b9bee1a46875d123d2f49bbeb0a91474118cf', 'hex');
var publicKeyB = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKeyB);
console.log(publicKeyB.toString('hex'))

// Encrypting the message for B.
eccrypto.encrypt(publicKeyB, Buffer.from("msg to b")).then(function(encrypted) {
  // B decrypting the message.
  eccrypto.decrypt(privateKeyB, encrypted).then(function(plaintext) {
    console.log("Message to part B:", plaintext.toString());
  });
});
```